# Efficiently Left Joining Two Tables on Multiple Fields in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-orm

I would like to left outer join on these tables.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    date = models.CharField()
    other_field = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication_date = models.CharField()
```

The sql query resulting from the django orm I am looking for should be like

```
select title, author, name as nam from book 
left outer join author on (book.author = author.id AND book.title = author.email)
```

How to achieve this? I tried using FilteredRelation but I am not getting the syntax correctly or is it impossible using django ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a **left outer join** using the **annotate()** and **F()** expressions.

**Raw SQL Query:**

```
select title, author.name as nam, publication_date
from book
left outer join author on book.author = author.name

from django.db.models import F

queryset = Book.objects.annotate(
nam=F('author__name')
).values('title', 'nam', 'publication_date')
```

**Note**: Django does not support **SQL queries** directly. If you want to see the **SQL query** of the above **queryset**.

```
print(str(queryset.query))
```

See more how to use **F()** expression: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/expressions/

**AND clause**,
**sample Query**:

```
select title, author.name as nam, publication_date
from book
left outer join author on book.author = author.name
WHERE publication_date >= '2020-01-01' AND author.date = '2023-10-26'
```

Comment: This results in a left outer join with the same ON condition (book.author = author.id). However, what I intended to achieve is to add AND book.title = author.email to the existing ON condition. I have already attempted to use FilteredRelation, but it is not applicable for my scenario.

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Although it generates two out joins I got to learn a new way of joining. Do you think its not possible to add another condition in the AND clause itself

Comment: I noticed that the second join is also being created with the primary_key in author table authori.id. The second condition in the ON clause I wanted was with another field of the author table which is not a primary_key